# Levelling newly opened area between rooms

Tags: flooring

We removed a wall to make a kitchen bigger - to use as an eating area.

The kitchen has vinyl flooring, which we are now changing to porcelain tiles.

The way it is now, there is about 1/2 inch rise on the kitchen side.

How can we cover the space where the wall was, so that the floors will be mostly level?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. It sounds like you need to lay 1/2" chipboard in the "new" area - If you could edit a photo into the question, it would probably help people understand the situation better.

Answer (score 1):

My carpenter's solution was simply to bridge the gap with a threshold, with its underside cut differentially to compensate for the difference. Having a clearly raised area between the two, with slopes on either side, is less likely to be a trip hazard than a smaller but sharper transition.

[image: photo of lr threshold showing contour]

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: Raise the lower floor by covering it in cementboard or plywood (depending on what you plan to cover it in, if you're planning to re-do it), or keep the floors at differing heights and use a transition piece like the one keshlam posted to hide it.